# Can I not use a function in an insert statement?

Tags: sql, sas, sql-insert

It seems as though I cannot use a SAS function in an insert statement:

```
proc sql;

     create table tq84_tab (col char(100));
     insert into  tq84_tab values (repeat('foo ', 10));

quit;
```

When I run the code, I am getting:

```
insert into  tq84_tab values (repeat('foo ', 10));
  ----     -----
   22       26
  202      200  

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, +, -, MISSING, NULL, USER.   
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Am I doing something wrong or is my suspiscion indeed the case?

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `select` rather than `values`?

Comment: `select` rather than `values` causes a similar error.

Comment: I don't think you can use any function in the `values` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No/Maybe.

With `insert .. values` you have to you fixed values, no functions.

In this simple case you'd be able to help yourself with SAS macro - call the SAS function using %sysfunc macro function, that "pre-processes" your code.

```
proc sql;
     create table tq84_tab (col char(100));
     insert into  tq84_tab values ("%sysfunc(repeat(foo, 10))");
     select * from tq84_tab;
quit;
```

Comment: @René Nyffenegger : Is the goal to create ONE VARIABLE containing "foo" repeated 10 times (foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo) or to create 10 VARIABLES each one contains the world "foo"?

Comment: *One* variable with the value `foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo `.

Answer (score 1):

For an item to appear N times you repeat it N-1 times.  You'll also need to macro quote the item if you want it to repeat a trailing space:

```
insert into tq84_tab values ("%sysfunc(repeat(%str(foo ), 9))");
```

You can also create a dummy table with only one row.  Then use run-time functions to construct the value to insert.

```
create table onerow (ignore_me char(0));
insert into onerow values ('');
insert into tq84_tab select (repeat("foo ",9)) as col from onerow;
```

onerow is acting as Oracle's DUAL or SQL Server's bare select (no from).